# PHP PDO prepare transaction statement (Two inserts)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have tried to insert two insert intos through a transaction statement but it did not work. The console is giving me database errors. I have checked the documentation http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers and it is obvious I am missing something.

The goal is simply insert into two different tables different information. I tried the following:

```
// create record
function create(){

    try {

        $stmt->beginTransaction();

        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
                    SET user_id = ?, ";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // bind values to be inserted

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->user_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $query2 = "INSERT INTO legalcases_report
                SET user_id = ?, ";

        // prepare query statement 2
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query2);

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception) {
        $stmt->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Where are you recieving the values from?

Comment: from another php page but data have been past before with just one insert. I suppose the error must come from somewhere else.

Comment: 500 Server error normally means that for some reason, on the server side, something is stopping access to the website. It's not normally caused by SQL statements

Comment: look at your code again *very carefully*. what's missing here? one tiny missing thing here that'll ruin your day.

Comment: Plus your `bindParam` should all be `bindValue`

Comment: `$stmt->execute()` <<<<<<<<<<<<< see what's missing here? syntax error; off-topic.

Comment: oh,oh,oh I know hahaha `;` I'm an idiot

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't see any difference between `bindParam` and `bindValue` in this example.

Comment: @Barmar either way; it's a syntax error (so far)  `$stmt->execute()` if that's the OP's actual code.

Comment: I don't think that would cause a 500 Error though. just not display anything

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);   ... ....  .... error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: could also be a variable scope issue, could be 1 of 50 things. check your logs.

Comment: I added the ; after  $stmt->execute() and still not working.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the page if it's something with the page then the error that is not 500 Server should pop up on the page. If it doesn't then you have a problem with the server not the code

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)  on line 116 that line is the one with } catch (Exception) {

Comment: replace `catch (Exception)`  with `catch (Exception ex) ` and see if that works

Comment: It did not work adding ex but I added  and works. Still I do not know the login behind it :(                                                                    } catch (Exception $e) {
  $stmt->rollBack();
  echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: that should be fine. do you still recieve the same error?

Comment: Yes it works It seems I need to study more. Thank you all!

Comment: Why has nobody noticed that this code is complete and utter nonsence! **Refactor all this code** thats the polite ways of saying throw it away and start again from scratch. Learn to crawl before you try to run

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems in this code, I hope I can catch them all

```
// create record
function create(){

    try {
        // transaction work on a connection and not a statement
        //$stmt->beginTransaction();
        $this->conn->beginTransaction();


        // Incorrect syntax for an INSERT command
        // Error - Trailing comma in sytax
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
                    SET user_id = ?, ";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // bind values to be inserted

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->user_id);
        $stmt->execute();


        // Incorrect syntax for an INSERT command
        // Error - Trailing comma in sytax
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO legalcases_report
                SET user_id = ?, ";

        // prepare query statement 2
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query2);

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->user_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        // commit also works on a connection object
        //$stmt->commit();
        $this->conn->commit();

        return true;

    // PDO generates a PDOException so you should really catch that,
    // it will fallback to the parent Exception object, BUT
    // there may be times when you want to catch them seperately
    // from the same try block, so use the correct one or both

    } catch (PDOException $pex) {
        $this->con->rollback();
        $pex->getMessage();
        exit; // because you have a serious problem

        // or throw your own exception to the calling code
        throw new Exception('Create user failed ' . $pex->getMessage());
    }

}
```

[Incorrect syntax for an INSERT command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

[The PHP PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should use PDO object, not PDOStatement:

```
try {
     $this->conn->beginTransaction();
...
     $this->conn->commit();
```

Comment: There are about 100 errors before you get to that line

Comment: You guess they should?